# Table paging in query results table

Tags: pagination, jdeveloper, jqueryform

I have a query form with table in a page and I'm trying to use paging instead of using scroll to see all the data returned by the query.

I have found a link that explains how can I do it [site1](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/table_pagination_with_jdeveloper_11) and it works, but when I try to access one page ahead, for example page 400 or 1000 it takes too long to return that data.

I also have found another one [site2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/web.1111/b31974/bcadvvo.htm) that explains that I have to change som properties in the VO of that data. I have tryed to use both simultaneous, only the second one but with no success.

Is there a way to do it that does not take too long to fetch the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to put pagination to work, changing this

In the VO
   Sector Tunning
      All Rows;
      In Batches of: 100

Component Table
    Appearance / ScrollPolicy - page
    Behaviour / AutoHeightRows - 0
    Style / StyleClass - AFStretchWidth

Answer (score 0):

Visit your iterator tree in the pageDef file and set the `rangeSize` on the iterator.

Also make sure to check VO definition as iterator changes wouldn't override VO settings.

Comment: The rangeSize is with the value of 25.
How can I check if doe not override? When I make deploy and try to go to another page, the page won't show and it doesn't show me anything in the Log.
Does the fact of the table presents the returned values from a query form, could have something to do with it?